# Filter parent based on child parameters in JPA 2

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, jpql

I have a few unidirectional `@OneToMany` relationships as this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
public class Parent {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "ParentID")
    private List<Child1> childList1;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "ParentID")
    private List<Child2> childList2;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Child1")
public class Child1 {
    private int someProperty;
    // other properties
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Child2")
public class Child2 {
    private int someProperty;
    // other properties
}
```

I'm trying to get all Parents with `child1.someProperty=10` and `child2.someProperty=20`. Could anyone please help ?
I tried using Join :

```
Root<Parent> root = criteria.from(Parent.class);
ListJoin<Parent, Child1> join = root.join(Parent_.childList1);
criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get(Child1_.someProperty), 10);
```

However, this returns a `Parent` for every `Child1`:

```
Parent----Child1(someProperty=10)
Parent----Child1(someProperty=10)
```

I would like the result to be :

```
        /Child1(someProperty=10)
       /   
Parent/---Child1(someProperty=10)
      \
       \
        \Child2(someProperty=20)
```

Could anyone please help with this? I would prefer JPA Criteria, JPQL is fine though .

 I'm prepared to make minor changes in my entity structure, if it helps (*minor* changes, like making the relationship bidirectional ?)
Thanks. 
I'm using hibernate as the JPA implementation, by the way.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#distinct-boolean-

Comment: @JBNizet I'm afraid that does not solve it. I've omitted some properties from `Child1` , for brevity, and these may differ. As in a `Parent` with two `Child1` entities : `Child1(someProperty=10, otherProperty=25)` and `Child1(someProperty=10, otherProperty=30)`

Comment: If what you mean is that the query returns parents with children other than the ones with the given child properties, that's notmal and expected. The query determines which parents are returned. But the children of a parent are the children of the parent, all of them, whatever the query you used to select the parents. If you want to filter children, you need a query selecting children, not parents.

Comment: @JBNizet My bad, turns out you were right. Could you post it as an answer so that I can accept it ?

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `setDistinct(true)` on your query.
Results you are getting are valid join results mapped row by row to entities. Adding distinct will enable root aggregation resulting i parent having `N` children as what I belive is what you expect.